# React Material-UI child class pseudo

Tags: reactjs, css-selectors, material-ui

Does anybody know how to add ::after in child element?

CSS I expect to run:

```css
dt {
  float: left;
}

dt::after {
  content: "："
}
```

My code. `::after` doesn't work well.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    dlist: {
      '& dt': {
        float: 'left',
      '& dt::after': {
        content: '":"',
        },
      },
    },
  }),
);

const Report = (props: any) => {
  const styles = useStyles();
  return (
    <dl className={styles.dlist}>
      <dt>JPY</dt>
      <dd>100</dd>
      <dt>USD</dt>
      <dd>1</dd>
    </dl>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nesting `& dt::after` inside `& dt`. Since the ampersand (`&`) is evaluated to be the parent selector of `& dt::after`, it will be evaluated to `dlist dt dt::after`, which fails to select any elements.

Instead of nesting the `& dt::after` object inside `& dt`, try moving the object out of `& dt`:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  dlist: {
    "& dt": {
      float: "left"
    },
    "& dt::after": {
      content: '":"'
    }
  }
}));
```

Comment: Thank you. I can't tell the difference between your code and my code.

Comment: I moved your closing curly brace (`},`) from line 9 to line 6. This removes the nesting of `& dt::after` inside `& dt`

Comment: Thank you! I found my code was badly formatted.